# Define a functions return type so it'll be shown in the tooltip when writing a function call

Tags: javascript, function, return-type

I want to be able to set a functions return type so that my IDE can apply Intellisense.

e.g. i have a function that takes an object and creates/returns a HTMLElement from that.
I want that when i call that function like that:

```
var myElement = document.createElementWithProperties({elementType: 'div', id: 'myElement',style:{background: 'blue'}});
```

On the next Line when i enter "myElement." it would suggest me for example appendChild.

[image: document.createElement example]

Comment: What IDE are you even using?

Comment: @Bergi Visual Studio Code

Comment: With which plugins? Just the Js language server?

Comment: @Bergi No specific plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could decorate your function with a [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started.html) documentation block. For example some thing like this:

```js
/**
 * Creates an element with the specified properties.
 *
 * @param {object} The properties to create the element with.
 * @return {HTMLElement} The HTML element.
 */
function createElementWithProperties(obj) {
    // Do stuff!
}
```

Note: This doesn't seem to work, in Visual Studio Code, when extending the native document object but should work fine as a stand alone function or as part of a user defined object.

Comment: No "plain" way? Sad:(

Comment: maybe in combination with:
document.createElementsWithProperties = createElementsWithProperties;
It'll work